Accessing in-transit encryption enabled Elasticache with Spring Redis, throws an error for the stringRedisTemplate.keys method
We have an in-transit encryption enabled AWS Elasticache instance. We're trying to access the instance from our Spring boot microservice with Spring data redis SSL enabled.
LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
                .useSsl().and()
                .shutdownTimeout(Duration.ZERO)
                .build();
return new LettuceConnectionFactory(new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort), clientConfig);

But enabling SSL gives an error, for the method StringRedisTemplate.keys()
io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR unknown command 'keys', with args beginning with: IndexKey:abc_prefix*

Can this be due to some restriction with the method StringRedisTemplate.keys(), with enabling SSL. This method works fine when SSL is diabled.

Spring boot RedisTemplate, keys method has the annotation @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Set<K> keys(K pattern) {}

When I replace the keys method with Scan, the issue got resolved.
I think the issue was the security risks with using the keys method.

For the next searcher that will land here, just an anecdote - the problem with keys is that its heavy on CPU, will block all action till finish and might fail your server and/or your client.
The command traverse all keys in the server, and redis being single threaded cannot perform any other task, and when finish, depend on data size, send a huge response back.
It is not recommended to use it at all, and it is deprecated.
This is the reason SCAN exist.
